# RecyclerView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android

I always worked with `ListView`, and within a `ScrollView` I used the `setListViewHeightBasedOnItems` method to set the height according to the number of items in the list.

Now i'm working with `RecyclerView`, however this method to set the height does not work anymore, what should i do to use `RecyclerView` within a `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great things about `RecyclerView` is that it makes it a little more clear when either a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` is not an appropriate widget to use in a given situation.

`RecyclerView` is designed to recycle Views that are not on screen to make scrolling more efficient. If you want a container for a group of Views to have a height equal to the height of all of its children, then *each of its children must first be laid out and measured*. One View for each item must be inflated, thus defeating the purpose of allowing Views to be recycled in the first place.

Instead, you may want to look into using a simple `LinearLayout` for this purpose. You can still use an `Adapter` to populate the View, and you will get the behavior you want out of the box. If you want to use an adapter to populate a `LinearLayout`, your code might look something like this:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_container);
Adapter listAdapter = createListAdapter();

final int childCount = listAdapter.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    View child = listAdapter.getView(i, null, container);
    container.addView(child);
}
```

Comment: It really was the best option, I had neither the adapter, just a looping adding views as the result of my webservice. Very, very thanks.